# Why is it when I debug my table which is an Actor in my stage the widget orientation is mirrored

Tags: java, libgdx, widget, stage, scene2d

I am using the libgdx scene2d.ui library to create a stage and a table as the Actor. I have created a FitViewport using final variables for the width and height. I am also using the FillViewports OrthographicCamera. when I run debug on my table the Widgets cells are mirrored to the rest of the cells.

I have read the documentation and the wiki on scene2d.ui and as much as I can find on widgets, tables, stages and nothing relating to my issue. I thought maybe it was a scaling thing like if the widgets were larger then the cell bounds but I've scaled the widgets down with minWidth and perfWidth nothing changes. I've tried different view ports, tried a separate Orthographic camera and tried different skins all resulting in the same thing and its like this on all my screens

[[image: picture of my table debug]]

everything seems to be working correctly but my OCD is driving me nuts over this. if anyone could give me some incite that would be awesome. or just tell me that its a glitch in the matrix and its not going to cause issues down the road and to move on with my coding.

This is my gameScreen Manager code

```
package com.armadillo.game.screens;

import com.armadillo.game.Arma;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class GameScreenManager {
    private Arma game;
    //viewport variables
    protected Viewport screensViewport;
    protected Viewport playViewport;


    //screen variables
    private LoadingScreen loadingScreen;
    private MenuScreen menuScreen;
    private PlayScreen playScreen;
    private OptionsScreen optionsScreen;
    private HighScoreScreen highScoreScreen;
    private PauseScreen pauseScreen;
    private GameOverScreen gameoverScreen;

    //screen switch values
    public final static int MENU = 0;
    public final static int PLAY = 1;
    public final static int OPTIONS = 2;
    public final static int HIGH_SCORE = 3;
    public final static int PAUSE = 4;
    public final static int GAMEOVER = 5;



    public GameScreenManager(Arma game) {
        this.game = game;
        //create and apply viewport with a OrthographicCamera centered to the viewport
        screensViewport = new FitViewport(Arma.GAME_WORLD_WIDTH , Arma.GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT );
        screensViewport.apply(true);

        //create, set and initiate the screen to loadingScreen
        loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen(this.game, this);
        this.game.setScreen(loadingScreen);

    }

    //method used to switch states of screens
    public void changeScreen(int screen) {
        switch (screen) {
            case MENU:
                if (menuScreen == null)
                    menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this.game, this);
                this.game.setScreen(menuScreen);
                break;
            case PLAY:
                if (playScreen == null)
                    playScreen = new PlayScreen(this.game, this);
                this.game.setScreen(playScreen);
                break;
            case OPTIONS:
                if (optionsScreen == null)
                    optionsScreen = new OptionsScreen(this.game, this);
                this.game.setScreen(optionsScreen);
                break;
            case HIGH_SCORE:
                if (highScoreScreen == null)
                    highScoreScreen = new HighScoreScreen(this.game, this);
                this.game.setScreen(highScoreScreen);
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                if (pauseScreen == null)
                    pauseScreen = new PauseScreen(this.game, this);
                this.game.setScreen(pauseScreen);
                break;
            case GAMEOVER:
                if (gameoverScreen == null)
                    gameoverScreen = new GameOverScreen(this.game, this);
                this.game.setScreen(gameoverScreen);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Options Screen code

```
package com.armadillo.game.screens;

import com.armadillo.game.Arma;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Event;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.EventListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;


public class OptionsScreen implements Screen {
    //passed through variables
    private Arma game;
    private GameScreenManager gsm;
    
    //screen layout variables
    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;
    private Skin skin;
    private TextButton mainMenu;
    
    //Label variables
    private Label titleLabel;
    private Label volumeMusicLabel;
    private Label musicEnabledLabel;
    private Label volumeSoundLabel;
    private Label soundEnabledLabel;

    //slider and CheckBox variables
    private final Slider musicVolSlider;
    private final Slider soundVolSlider;
    private final CheckBox musicCheckBox;
    private final CheckBox soundCheckBox;


    public OptionsScreen(Arma game, GameScreenManager gsm) {
        this.game = game;
        this.gsm = gsm;
       
        //create the stage using screenViewport parameters
        stage = new Stage(gsm.screensViewport);
        table = new Table();
        table.top();
        table.setDebug(true);
        stage.addActor(table);
        
        //create the skin that will used for layout design
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/neon-ui2.json"));

        //create labels
        titleLabel = new Label("Options", skin);
        volumeMusicLabel = new Label("Music Volume", skin);
        musicEnabledLabel = new Label("Music", skin);
        volumeSoundLabel = new Label("Sound Volume", skin);
        soundEnabledLabel = new Label("Sound", skin);
        mainMenu = new TextButton("Main Menu", skin);
        
        //create and set Music and sound slider to adjust volume of the music
        musicVolSlider = new Slider(0, 1, 0.1f, false, skin);
        musicVolSlider.setValue(game.getOptions().getMusicVolume());
        soundVolSlider = new Slider(0, 1, 0.1f, false, skin);
        soundVolSlider.setValue(game.getOptions().getSoundVolume());
        
        //create and set music and sound CheckBox to controll music on and off
        musicCheckBox = new CheckBox("ON/OFF", skin);
        musicCheckBox.setChecked(game.getOptions().isMusicEnabled());
        soundCheckBox = new CheckBox("ON/OFF", skin);
        soundCheckBox.setChecked(game.getOptions().isSoundEnabled());
        
        //sets the table size to its parent which is the stage
        table.setFillParent(true);
        
        //add labels sliders and checkBox's to table
        table.add(titleLabel);
        table.row();

        table.add(musicEnabledLabel);
        table.add(musicCheckBox);
        table.row();

        table.add(volumeMusicLabel);
        table.add(musicVolSlider);
        table.row();

        table.add(soundEnabledLabel);
        table.add(soundCheckBox);
        table.row();

        table.add(volumeSoundLabel);
        table.add(soundVolSlider);
        table.row();

        table.add(mainMenu).size(320, 60);


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        //set the stage to accept input
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        
        //takes input from user and activates skin changes
        mainMenu.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                gsm.changeScreen(gsm.MENU);

            }
        });
        
        //an input from user to register sliders and checkboxes
        musicVolSlider.addListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean handle(Event event) {
                game.getOptions().setMusicVol(musicVolSlider.getValue());
                return false;
            }
        });

        soundVolSlider.addListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean handle(Event event) {
                game.getOptions().setSoundVol(soundVolSlider.getValue());
                return false;
            }
        });

        musicCheckBox.addListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean handle(Event event) {
                boolean enabled = musicCheckBox.isChecked();
                game.getOptions().setMusicEnabled(enabled);
                return false;
            }
        });

        musicCheckBox.addListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean handle(Event event) {
                boolean enabled = soundCheckBox.isChecked();
                game.getOptions().setSoundEnabled(enabled);
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //sets background color and clears screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, .1f, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        //draws the stage and all its components
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        //updates viewport and camera adjusting sizes locally
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);


    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        //dispose of the stage helps with memory leaks and garbage collection
        stage.dispose();


    }
}
```

and this is my main class Arma

```
package com.armadillo.game;

import com.armadillo.game.screens.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class Arma extends Game {
    //the game world size
    public static final int GAME_WORLD_WIDTH = 1600;
    public static final int GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT = 900;
    
    //assetmanger for music sound
    public static AssetManager manager;
    
    //Options object used to access option preferences
    private GameOptions options;
    
    //entity variables
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    public BitmapFont font;
    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Texture img;

    private Music music;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        //create entities
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        manager = new AssetManager();
        options = new GameOptions();
        manager.load("audio/music.wav", Music.class);
        manager.finishLoading();
        music = manager.get("audio/music.wav", Music.class);
        
        //create and initiate the GameScreenManager
        GameScreenManager gsm = new GameScreenManager(this);
    }

    public GameOptions getOptions() {
        return this.options;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
        //constantly check audio options
        music.setVolume(options.getMusicVolume());
        if (options.isMusicEnabled()) {
            music.play();
        } else if (!options.isMusicEnabled()){
            music.stop();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        //dispose of the stage, batch and manager. helps with memory leaks and garbage collection
        batch.dispose();
        music.dispose();
        manager.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed this too, it was not like this before. It must be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in LibGDX v1.10.0 (based on my testing). I don't see relevant information in the changelog; probably was too minor to bother mentioning? Or just incidentally cleaned up somehow.

https://libgdx.com/news/2021/04/gdx-1-10